# preventDefault() does not work

Tags: jquery, redirect, preventdefault

I have an animated navigation via some jQuery functions. It all works fine but one thing is  making me crazy. The last item (item nb. 5) should redirect you to new page but it does not happen. I have the condition on first few first lines of code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > a').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).parent().has('p')) {        
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('li a').next('p').stop().slideUp();
            $(this).next('p').stop().slideDown();
            $('li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).next('p').stop().slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }

    })

})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/SQTcN/2/

Comment: `$(this)` is not what you think it is. Do `console.log` and see what `$(this)` actually is.

Comment: What exactly do I have to write in console? I am noob in javascript :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [`has(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.
>
> **Returns: jQuery**

`.has()` returns a jQuery object.

Use `.find('p').length` or `.has('p').length` instead of `.has('p')`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > a').on('click', function(e) {
        
        if ($(this).parent().find('p').length) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('li a').next('p').stop().slideUp();
            $(this).next('p').stop().slideDown();
            $('li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).next('p').stop().slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SQTcN/6/)

Answer (score 1):

`.has()` returns a jQuery object not a boolean

Just change your if to this:

```
if (!($(this).hasClass("odkaz"))) { 
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li > a').on('click', function(e) {
        if (!($(this).hasClass("odkaz"))) { 
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('li a').next('p').stop().slideUp();
            $(this).next('p').stop().slideDown();
            $('li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).next('p').stop().slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }

    })

})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SQTcN/4/)

Comment: I know this way, but it was not my intention to do that by CSS classes

Answer (score 1):

[`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) doesn't return a boolean.  It returns a jQuery object.  From the docs:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element.

So, you'd need to do something like:

```
if($(this).parent().has('p').length)
```

Or better yet, you don't need to traverse up to the parent to traverse back down.  Just simply do:

```
if($(this).siblings('p').length)
```